# Swiftmailer not sending emails Symfony2 with one domain

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I am configuring a some mailing things into my Symfony2 project and I am having some trouble.

If I use one of my companies' email domains, Swiftmailer does nothing, it says that mail has been sent (send() method returns > 0) but I don't receive anything.

If I configure it to send from a gmail adress, it works properly; if I configure it to send from another domain of mine, it works too.

What could cause this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: check spam folder direcotry on your mail account.

Comment: Check your companies SMTP server log.